# Displaying an image with full path

Tags: php, html

I want to display an image stored on my website but I only have the full path: "C:/xampp/htdocs/images/shop/2319556577.jpg",

Path to where all images are stored: "C:/xampp/htdocs/images/shop/",

And the image name: "2319556577.jpg"

And the src tag does not support a full path so my question is: How do I get the correct path to my image so that it is displayable in a `<img src="...">`

Comment: Use a relative path like './images/shop/2319556577.jpg'? (depending from where the file is located on your webfolder)

Comment: @Wimanicesir The goal is that I could use the full path of the image to display the image on whatever page I like within "/htdocs"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should keep the image in a specific folder within your project files for your website at the root directory.
Then you can use relative path to reference that image.

Say your project files are in root folder `Project`. Inside your project folder you can create another folder say `static` and keep the image in that folder. Now to reference the image from your html file you can use relative indexing.   
Like `<img src="static\<img-file>.jpg">....`

This works if you are using html file or jinja templates. If you are working with asp or jsp files then it won't work that way. You then need to reference images from cache folders within your project files.